# Python pip: Can't install matplotlib (ConnectTimeoutError)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pip

Running the following command:

```
pip install matplotlib --disable-pip-version-check
```

Gives the following output:

```
Collecting matplotlib
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02D9D0F0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02D9DE70>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02D9D890>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02D9D8D0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip
._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x02D9DD90>, 'Connection to pypi.python.
org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/matplotlib/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib
```

Comment: Can you install any other packages? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: The same behavior for other packages. How can I check whether or not I'm behind a proxy?

Comment: if your internet is ok then it's about proxy issue!

Comment: look at [this link](http://www.irvingc.com/posts/10)

Answer (score 3):

Check your Internet connection.

It seems that the Internet is unreachable for you. Less likely, PyPi is experiencing temporary problems and you should try connecting later.

Comment: My internet works fine, I'm posting this question with the same connection. Could it be a firewall or some other type of security restriction?

Comment: @zvisofer, it could be almost anything including firewalls and PyPi-side problems. Can you access the PyPi website via your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can access their website

Comment: @zvisofer, then try to update pip [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) or just download and install matplotlib manually.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple methods step by step:-

1. Download  `matplotlib(.whl)` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. matplotlib also Requires `numpy`, `dateutil`, `pytz`, `pyparsing`, `cycler`, `setuptools`

   process:
   open>python27>>Scripts>copy and paste matplotlib.whlfile
3. open cmd on python27>Scripts>`pip install matplotlib-1.5.1-cp27-none win_amd64.whl`

I think this is the simplest install method.
Just try it if you face again same problem then ping me.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution - I found an executable installer [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/downloads)

Didn't find it with Google before.

Answer (score 0):

Try ignoring the cache:

`pip install matplotlib --no-cache`

No idea how this works, because when it said `ConnectionTimeoutError`, I assumed that it was not using the cache. If this works for anyone, I'd love to hear an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Even though this case had been solved i had the same issue with my pro laptop because the firewalls were restricting me. The answer didn't helped me so i'm posting the way i succeeded for people that might be in the same situation than me.

You just have to download the package locally (i'll take seaborn as an exemple) at: https://pypi.org/seaborn/ and click on 'download files' and then download the package.tar.gz extension. Once it's done unzip it with an external tool (i.e. 7-Zip File Manager for me) and you should end up with mutliple folders like .github, ci, doc,licences, seaborn, etc...

Now all you have to do is to cut and paste the folder named after the package you want (seaborn for me) within python\Lib\site-packages which should be in something like this :
C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages

PS: I'm not sure if doing it this way enable you to have access to all the features of the package but it's working fine for me for now. So do not hesitate to tell me if doing it like this is a good idea or not...